# Tomcat Apache server restart required too frequently

Tags: apache, tomcat, server

It is troublesome to restart he server every time content gets changed. Is there any utility that detects if the content edited does not affect the working of code eg. changing variable value?

Comment: [Why are you restarting on each deploy](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am curious what type of change you're making. When you make a change in javascript, there is no need to restart the Tomcat server. But if you modify any thing which needs to compile then only you need to restart after recompilation. But you can configure tomcat for reload automatically your servlets, configure the attribute re-loadable to true of the Context. Take a look at context.xml.